# Qlikview conditionally hide expression in pivot table

Tags: qlikview

Struggling with a way to hide an expression on certain rows in my pivot table below.  Basically, I want to be able to hide my expression 'Cumulative' when the FINANCIAL_PLAN_TYPE is not equal to 'OB_VARIANCE_TO_T1'.  I figured out a way to change the text format on the lines with other FINANCIAL_PLAN_TYPE so that it appears hidden (what is showing in the picture below), but I'd really like the whole row to go away in these cases.

Additionally, I do not want to see a Total on the Cumulative lines if possible, but I do want to keep them on the Sum(AMOUNT) lines.

My expression for Cumulative is:

```
sum(aggr(Rangesum(above(sum({<YEAR={"$(vYear_Current)"},FINANCIAL_PLAN_TYPE={"OB_VARIANCE_TO_T1"}>}AMOUNT),0,MONTH_NUM)), FINANCIAL_PLAN_TYPE, MONTH_NUM))
```

I tried to use the function Only, as well as, I tried conditionally enabling/disabling the expression but I can't seem to get it to work.  Any ideas would be great.  Thanks!

[image: Pivot Table]

FINAL SOLUTION:

1) Load Inline Table

```
Load * Inline
[MyDim
  Cumulative
  Vals
];
```

2) Created calculated dimension to combine the two desired dimensions into one and show blank ('') in cases that you don't want to show (this leaves one blank line on the pivot but there is probably a way to hide that too):

```
=If(MYDim='Cumulative' and FINANCIAL_PLAN_TYPE='OB_VARIANCE_TO_T1','Orig Budg Cumulative Variance',if(MYDim='Cumulative' and FINANCIAL_PLAN_TYPE='LE_VARIANCE_TO_T1','LE Cumulative Variance',if(MYDim <> 'Cumulative',FINANCIAL_PLAN_TYPE,'')))
```

3) Create a new expression that does one calculation in the case of your made up dimension = Value A and something else in case your calculated dimension = Value B

```
If(MYDim='Cumulative' and (FINANCIAL_PLAN_TYPE='OB_VARIANCE_TO_T1' OR FINANCIAL_PLAN_TYPE='LE_VARIANCE_TO_T1'),If(ColumnNo()=0,'',sum(aggr(Rangesum(above(sum({<YEAR={"$(vYear_Current)"}, DEPARTMENT={"20820"}, ACCT_TYPE={"Capital"}>}AMOUNT),0,MONTH_NUM)),
FINANCIAL_PLAN_TYPE, MONTH_NUM))),IF(MYDim='Vals', SUM({<ACCT_TYPE={"Capital"},DEPARTMENT={"20820"}>}AMOUNT)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot hide expression on some of the rows - not possible in Qlikview.
The workaround is to create a dummy floating table that holds the second column as a dimension and then use it in your chart instead of the two expressions. Then you will have one expression that says something like that :

```
    If ( dummyField = 'Cummulative' and  = 'OB_VARIANCE_TO_T1', 
           {Use your second expression here} , 
         If (dummyField = 'sum(Amount)', {use your original first expression here}))
```

Regarding the Total, check out this [link](https://www.qliktastic.com/2016/03/03/qlikview-pivot-table-average/) in the "Tricking the Pivot Table" section

Comment: Neat trick with the ColumnNo()! Thank you for that link.  I'm not sure I understand the concept of a dummy floating table.  I'm new to Qlikview..could you elaborate a bit more... as in are you referring to doing something in the load script or doing something with a table in the sheet object?

Comment: in your script just create an inline table with one field and 'Cummulative' and 'Amount' as Values.

Comment: sweet .. I got it now.  Thank you